# How to interprete this も?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20181007/k10011662381000.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-main_003

The sentence in question:
長野県内でキノコ採りに出かけた人が死亡する事故が相次ぐ中、６日も上田市の山林でキノコ採りをしていた30代の女性が滑落して死亡しました。

My attempt at translation:
"In Nagano prefecture, during a series of accidents (= during accidents which happened one after another) where people died who had left to collect mushrooms, **on the sixth** of the month (octobre) in the Uedashi mountain forest, a woman of the age of 30 who was collecting mushrooms died slipping."

First, since I'm a bit skeptical about my overall interpretation, I wonder whether I interpreted も correctly here or not. Overall the article seems to report one particular incident where people died in an accident, however, since it speaks of a series of accidents, I'm not sure whether this "series" happened in a series of days or on a single day?
If the first option was true, then I guess も would make perfect sense as it depicts the 6th of octobre as another day where (such) accidents happened. 
If the second option was true though then I'm kind of out of ideas, because then there wouldn't be a day similar to the 6th octobre to which the も could relate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether this "series" happened in a series of days or on a single day?

Well, I don't think that mushroom picking is the kind of thing that causes mass-deaths on a single day. Furthermore, near the end of the article they mention that the other accidents have been happening since August (８月以降), so it really wouldn't make sense for it to be on a single day.

> If the first option was true, then I guess も would make perfect sense as it depicts the 6th of octobre as another day where (such) accidents happened.

Exactly, it makes perfect sense. :)